# Null value returnred with XML parsing in java using plane DOM parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I was trying to parse a collada(.dae) file in java using plane DOM parser. When I try to get value it returns me null. I tried with answers and suggestions from other discussions but was not a success. The code I used is below.

```
for(int k1=0;k1<meshlist.getLength();k1++) {
    Element geometryItr1 = (Element)geometrylist.item(k);

    NodeList trianglelist = geometryItr1.getElementsByTagName("triangles");

    //System.out.println("Triangles length is " + trianglelist.getLength());     

        for(int o=0;o<trianglelist.getLength();o++) {

            Element trichildnodes = (Element) trianglelist.item(o);
            NodeList inputs = trichildnodes.getElementsByTagName("input");
        NodeList p = trichildnodes.getElementsByTagName("p");
        Element ppp = (Element) p.item(0);
        System.out.println("Node Value " + ppp.getNodeValue());
        System.out.println(inputs.getLength() + "Input length");

        for(int in=0;in<inputs.getLength();in++) {

            Element inn = (Element) inputs.item(in);
            System.out.println(inn.getAttribute("semantic") + " " + inn.getAttribute("source") + " Attributes");

        }


        //System.out.println(p.getLength() +  " P's length" );
        //System.out.println("P's content " + ppp.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());


    }   
}
```

The XML is very large and I am posting a part which I was trying to parse.

```
<mesh>
  <source> </source>
  <source> </source>
  <source> </source>
  <triangles>
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <p> 24 262 2 72 72 72 72 2222 8198219  </p>
  <triangles>
  <triangles>
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <p> 24 262 2 72 72 72 72 2222 8198219  </p>
  <triangles>
  <triangles>
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <p> 24 262 2 72 72 72 72 2222 8198219  </p>
  <triangles>
  <triangles>
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <p> 24 262 2 72 72 72 72 2222 8198219  </p>
  <triangles>
</mesh>
```

I was trying to get the value of `<p>`. Everything works fine except getting p's value. But when I debug I can see the values, its associated with first child. I even tried using firstChild. I am completely lost with parsing trying to find out a solution on this. Please some one help me find a solution on How to get the value of p ?

When I use getTextContent instead I get the output like below:

```
NodeValue null
NodeValue 24 262 2 72 72 72 72 2222 8198219
NodeValue null
```

The output is blank for two tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using the `javax.xml.xpath` APIs available in the JDK/JRE since Java SE 5 to make the processing of your XML document easier:

```
package forum11688757;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse(new File("src/forum11688757/input.xml"));

        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/mesh/triangles/p", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for(int x=0; x<nodeList.getLength(); x++) {
            System.out.println(nodeList.item(x).getTextContent());
        }
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

```
<mesh>
  <source> </source>
  <source> </source>
  <source> </source>
  <triangles>
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <p> 24 262 2 72 72 72 72 2222 8198219  </p>
  </triangles>
  <triangles>
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <p> 24 262 2 72 72 72 72 2222 8198219  </p>
  </triangles>
  <triangles>
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <p> 24 262 2 72 72 72 72 2222 8198219  </p>
  </triangles>
  <triangles>
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <p> 24 262 2 72 72 72 72 2222 8198219  </p>
  </triangles>
</mesh>
```

**Output**

```
 24 262 2 72 72 72 72 2222 8198219  
 24 262 2 72 72 72 72 2222 8198219  
 24 262 2 72 72 72 72 2222 8198219  
 24 262 2 72 72 72 72 2222 8198219
```

**UPDATE**

You could also get the `p` elements using the following line of code.  You need to be careful though since it will get all `p` elements not just those in the `/mesh/triangles/p` path

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

The following approach will always get you the data you are looking for, even if `p` eleements are later added somewhere else in the document.

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/mesh/triangles/p", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `nodeValue()` of an `Element` is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) as being null.

Instead, you probably want to call [getTextContent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29). But beware that it has its own idiosyncrasies (if you call it on the root of a tree, it will concatenate the text of all elements in the tree).

Comment: I have tried with getTextContent() but didn't work. It prints some not all.

Comment: "Some not all" is not useful. Show exact output and what you expect for output.

Comment: That isn't the exact output from the program you show; for one thing, there should be output related to the "input" elements. If it is in fact output from the same line of code, then take a look at your data: you will find empty "p" elements.

Comment: And as a general comment: when you're creating debugging output, be as specific as possible. Rather than saying "NodeValue", you should say something like "<P> content". Even better, keep count of the number of times you've written this, and write "<p> content #1234".

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to iterate over the previous nodes if you don't need them.
For example it's how to print all the text content in `<p>` tags :

```
    File xmlPath = new File("test.xml");

    DocumentBuilderFactory fabrique = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    fabrique.setCoalescing(true);
    fabrique.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

    DocumentBuilder constructeur = fabrique.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document document = constructeur.parse(xmlPath);  
    document.setXmlVersion("1.0");
    Element racine = document.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList liste = racine.getElementsByTagName("p");

    for(int i=0; i<liste.getLength(); i++) {
        Element e = (Element)liste.item(i);  
        System.out.println(e.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
    }
```

You can use that and elaborate to obtain what you want I guess. If you want the attribute value, just use: `e.getAttribute("att_name")`.

Comment: Thanks. But I doesn't read the first and third <p> it displays nothing.

Comment: @VinayKumarjg I used the xml example you provide and it display well the 4 `<p>` content. I just replace the end `<triangles>` tags with `</triangles>`. If you miss entry, it's probably because you have kept your nested loop or because the xml file is not as you describe it in the example.